# Google Analytics + Unity3D = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tracker name cannot be empty

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I'm working on integration of Google Analytics plugin in Unity project for Android. In editor no problems seem to appear, but when I run my game on the Android device, I receive the following exception (visible in logcat):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tracker name cannot be empty at
>   com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics.getTracker(GoogleAnalytics.java:164)
>   at
>   com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics.getTracker(GoogleAnalytics.java:192)
>   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method) at
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source) at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in :0 at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr obj,
>   IntPtr methodID, UnitEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in :0 at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObkject._Call[AndroidJavaObject]
>   (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0 at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObkject.Call[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String
>   methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0

I got all the prefab fields filled in, there should be no empty names. What did I miss?

I'm using:

- Google Analytics plugin v3
- Unity v.5.3.6f1 on Mac OS Sierra v.10.12
- Android SDK has been recently updated
- Device is: ASUS TF201 with Android 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the matter of the problem. It was in the way I tried to create the GameObject. I tried to create it dynamically in the script (all fields were filled correctly and the game object name was specified) and received the mentioned above exception on device (editor version worked smoothly). After I added the prefab on the scene statically - the exception has gone. Hope it'll save time to someone.